# How to extract and remove elements from an html page

Tags: html, bash

Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>
        dasdfasd
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="eheth" class="sdfgdf">
    <div id="wrapper">


        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
    <div id="MainContent_0">
        blah blah blah
    </div>
    <div class="video"> </div>
    <div id="MainContent_2">
        blah blah blah 2
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to remove everything except what is in `<div id=MainContent_0>` and `<div id=MainContent_2>`. The real page is much more complicated than this, and there are many more pages that are similar that I would like to do this to, but 
I've heard about simplehtmldom, but I couldn't figure out how to use it. I would like for it to be at least semi-automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
$ xmllint --html \
  --xpath '//div[@id="MainContent_0" or @id="MainContent_2"]' file 2>/dev/null
```

### Output :

```
<div id="MainContent_0">
        blah blah blah
    </div><div id="MainContent_2">
        blah blah blah 2
    </div>
```

Comment: the xpath above can be shortened to `'//div[@id="MainContent_0" or @id="MainContent_2"]'`